# App Store Rejection - Memory pop-up

Tags: iphone, ios4, app-store

My team is developing an iPhone app which is very demanding in terms of memory. In order for a better user experience we are thinking of presenting a pop-up to the user upon startup stating the memory requirements and also a pop-up upon low memory.

Has anyone had a problem with such a solution, in terms of being rejected from the app store?

Thanks

Comment: First: unnecessary and annoying.  Second: how will this make a better user experience?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple, don't show any `UIAlertView` in a memory warning.

The user is not responsible to manage the memory for you. You need to take actions in memory pressure by releasing caches or other less important information.

iOS itself will release memory and kill other apps when it's needed.

To answer your question, I don't know if Apple reject apps for that reason, but they repeated more then once to not to do so.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, on iOS systems, specifying the memory requirements to the user is not relevant. Most smartphone users won't know the available memory and don't want to be bother by technical aspects. To be successful, your app need to be robust and that also means memory adaptive.

As far as i remember you can ask the system to give you the amount of free memory. Try to manage your memory consumption using it. There are many strategies. Common ones are to ask it periodically or ask it lazily only when you are going to load big data.

When you receive memory warning, try to reduce your memory footprint the more you can

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure anyone can say anything sensible about whether this behavior will be acceptable in the app store. I've never heard of an app trying it.

Philosophically, it seems counter to the HIG. Memory management is your job, not the user's. You could maybe give them some "usage information" on first launch asking them to close backgrounded apps when using this one, but putting a memory alert in front of the user just feels inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Apple might not be happy with an alert, but possibly some kind of subtle ui graph showing available memory abstractly would be ok, and probably a nicer experience as the user could see how what they were doing affects memory.